# How to resolve this issue in json object into php array

Tags: php, json

here i call one API,so they will return some response in **json object**,now i want convert the **json into array** so i am trying like **json_decode($response,true);** but i am getting error

---

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\he\rest.php on line 16
Array

i don't know how to resolve this error,

```html
   <?php 
  $request_url = 'http://www.domain.com/api/method/properties';
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close ($ch);
   echo "<pre>";
  print_r($response);// Here we can get the respoonse in 
  echo "</pre>"; 
  echo json_decode($response,true)//Notice: Array to string conversion in        C:\xampp\htdocs\he\rest.php on line 16
Array
   ?>



//Resposnse coming like this
[ {
  "createdBy" : "agent",
  "createdDate" : "2016-09-20T08:13:30.418Z",
  "lastModifiedBy" : null,
  "lastModifiedDate" : "2016-10-12T09:10:20.847Z",
  "id" : "57e387cef1a8a02f7a0c9613",
  "name" : "2BHK Apartment in Sanjay Nagar",
  "contactName" : null,
  "propertyPurpose" : "RESIDENTIAL"
  },
  {
  "createdBy" : "agent",
  "createdDate" : "2016-09-20T08:13:30.418Z",
  "lastModifiedBy" : null,
  "lastModifiedDate" : "2016-09-20T08:13:30.539Z",
  "id" : "57e387e1f1a8a02f7a0c9616",
  "name" : "2BHK Apartment in Mira Road",
  "contactName" : null,
  "propertyPurpose" : "RESIDENTIAL",
  }
]
```

Comment: What statement is "line 16"? And where do you try `json_decode()`?

Comment: Use var_dump to print the decoded array, not echo. Also, next time post the code that's actually generating the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've showed the exact code, it's pretty obvious!

When you write `echo json_decode($response,true);`:

- first `json_decode($response,true)` executes what you wanted, i.e. return *an array*
- then you try to `echo` this array, hence the notice: "Array to string conversion" (since `echo` expects a string).